# How to do xslt Muenchian grouping with some null attributes?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Slightly different to the standard Meunchain grouping as I'm dealing with a null(?) attribute for some of the tags that I'm transforming. I'd like the null groupings to be treated as their own individual group with the transformed output adding the grouped strings. Also if there is a grouping to do a count of how many there were.

```
<root>
<section>
    <subsection>
        <module>
            <comp>111</comp>
        </module>
        <module group='group01'>
            <comp>222</comp>
        </module>
        <module group='group01'>
            <comp>333</comp>
        </module>
        <module>
            <comp>444</comp>
        </module>
        <module>
            <comp>555</comp>
        </module>
    </subsection>
</section>
<section>
    <subsection>
        <module group ="group02">
            <comp>666</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group02">
            <comp>777</comp>
        </module>
        <module>
            <comp>888</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group03">
            <comp>999</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group03">
            <comp>101010</comp>
        </module>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
        <module group ="group04">
            <comp>11111</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group04">
            <comp>121212</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group05">
            <comp>131313</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group05">
            <comp>141414</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group06">
            <comp>151515</comp>
        </module>
        <module group ="group06">
            <comp>161616</comp>
        </module>
        <module>
            <comp>171717</comp>
        </module>
    </subsection>
</section>
```

Wanted output:

```
<AllSections>
<section>
    <subsection>
        <page>
            <content>111</content>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>222333</content>
            <count>2</count>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>444</content>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>555</content>
        </page>
    </subsection>
</section>
<section>
    <subsection>
        <page>
            <content>666777</content>
            <count>2</count>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>888</content>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>999101010</content>
            <count>2</count>
        </page>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
        <page>
            <content>111111121212</content>
            <count>2</count>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>131313141414161616</content>
            <count>3</count>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>151515</content>
        </page>
        <page>
            <content>171717</content>
        </page>
    </subsection>
</section>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your expected output correct? Why is 151515 output separately when it shown in the input as having a group of "group06". Similarly, why is 161616, which also has a group of "group06", output with 131313 and 141414, both of which have a group of "group05"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the elements with a **group** attribute, you are grouping by that attribute but also within the parent **subsection** element. Therefore you could start off by defining a key to group them this was

```
<xsl:key name="modules" match="module[@group]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group)" />
```

Next, you would need templates to match the various cases for the **module** elements. Firstly, you could have a template to match **module** elements with no **group** attribute, where you could format the output as required.

```
<xsl:template match="module[not(@group)]">
    <page>
        <content>
            <xsl:value-of select="comp"/>
        </content>
    </page>
 </xsl:template>
```

For modules, with **group** attributes you would need a match that checked that this particular **module** element occurred first in the group for the key defined above.

```
<xsl:template 
  match="module
    [@group]
    [generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]">
```

Within this template, you could then easily define a variable to hold the elements in the group, using the key, and then either output the child **comp** elements, or count them

```
<xsl:variable name="modules" select="key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))"/>
<page>
    <content>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$modules/comp/text()"/>
    </content>
    <count>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($modules)" />
     </count>
</page>
```

Finally, you would need a third template to match all other **module** elements (i.e. elements with a **group** attribute, but not first in the group) to ignore them, to ensure they don't get output twice. (The XSLT processor should always match more specific templates before this more generic one)

```
<xsl:template match="module"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="modules" match="module[@group]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group)"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <AllSections>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </AllSections>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="module[not(@group)]">
        <page>
            <content>
                <xsl:value-of select="comp"/>
            </content>
        </page>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="modules" select="key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))"/>
        <page>
            <content>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$modules/comp/text()"/>
            </content>
            <count>
                <xsl:value-of select="count($modules)" />
            </count>
        </page>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="module"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<AllSections>
    <section>
        <subsection>
            <page>
                <content>111</content>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>222333</content>
                <count>2</count>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>444</content>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>555</content>
            </page>
        </subsection>
    </section>
    <section>
        <subsection>
            <page>
                <content>666777</content>
                <count>2</count>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>888</content>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>999101010</content>
                <count>2</count>
            </page>
        </subsection>
        <subsection>
            <page>
                <content>11111121212</content>
                <count>2</count>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>131313141414</content>
                <count>2</count>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>151515161616</content>
                <count>2</count>
            </page>
            <page>
                <content>171717</content>
            </page>
        </subsection>
    </section>
</AllSections>
```

Comment: +1. One template with `<xsl:template match="root"><AllSections><xsl:apply-templates/></AllSections></xsl:template>` is missing it seems to produce the wanted result (although this is unrelated to the main grouping problem).

Comment: Ah yes. I hadn't spotted the renaming of the root element. I have amended my XSLT to include the template for that. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Time, thanks for such a complete answer. Quick question on extending this. I need to concat docs with 'content' as a file location rather than a string. With the non grouped elements I'm using :