# XSLT Concat html docs from a grouping transform

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

A transform (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862902/how-to-do-xslt-muenchian-grouping-with-some-null-attributes/12871809#12871809) groups based on an attribute (@group) and that attribute being null. Initially this was for just concat-ing strings but I now need to extend it so it uses the string as a file location and concats the docs if they are grouped - if not grouped it should use the string as a file it gets but doesn't need to join to anything else. The Transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="modules" match="module[@group]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group)"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <AllSections>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </AllSections>
</xsl:template>

<!-- NON GROUPED PART -->
<xsl:template match="module[not(@group)]">
    <page>
        <content>
            <xsl:value-of select="comp"/>
        </content>
    </page>
</xsl:template>

<!--GROUPED PART -->
<xsl:template match="module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="modules" select="key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))"/>
    <page>
        <content>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$modules/comp/text()"/>
        </content>
        <count>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($modules)" />
        </count>
    </page>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="module"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And Sample Input:

```
<root>
<section>
<subsection>
    <module>
        <comp>111</comp>
    </module>
    <module group='group01'>
        <comp>222</comp>
    </module>
    <module group='group01'>
        <comp>333</comp>
    </module>
    <module>
        <comp>444</comp>
    </module>
    <module>
        <comp>555</comp>
    </module>
</subsection>
</section>
<section>
<subsection>
    <module group ="group02">
        <comp>666</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group02">
        <comp>777</comp>
    </module>
    <module>
        <comp>888</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group03">
        <comp>999</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group03">
        <comp>101010</comp>
    </module>
</subsection>
<subsection>
    <module group ="group04">
        <comp>11111</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group04">
        <comp>121212</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group05">
        <comp>131313</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group05">
        <comp>141414</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group06">
        <comp>151515</comp>
    </module>
    <module group ="group06">
        <comp>161616</comp>
    </module>
    <module>
        <comp>171717</comp>
    </module>
</subsection>
```

The transform at the moment concats the comp strings if they are of the same group... doing this for the non-grouped parts so the string is used as a file location:

```
    <!-- NON GROUPED PART -->
<xsl:template match="module[not(@group)]">
    <page>
        <content>
            <xsl:variable name="var">
               <xsl:value-of select="comp"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('../myfile/', string($var)))"/>
        </content>
    </page>
</xsl:template>
```

At the moment the GROUPED PART will output:

...

```
<page>
        <content>strgin1string2</content>
        <count>2</count>
</page>
```

...

I need:

...

```
<page>
        <content>
         TEXT FROM FILE CALLED string1
         TEXT FROM FILE CALLED string2
        </content>
        <count>2</count>
</page>
```

...

Thanks!

Comment: Are these files XML files? With XSLT 1.0 all you can pull in with the `document` function are XML documents. Only XSLT 2.0 has `unparsed-text` to pull in non XML text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you simply want to pull in complete XML documents you can change your code to

```
<xsl:template match="module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="modules" select="key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))"/>
    <page>
        <content>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document($modules/comp)"/>
        </content>
        <count>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($modules)" />
        </count>
    </page>
</xsl:template>
```

[edit] I think my suggestion above works if the `comp` elements contain the complete URL. Your comment however suggests you want to concatenate a constant with each `comp`, in that case with XSLT 1.0 you need

```
<xsl:template match="module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="modules" select="key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))"/>
    <page>
        <content>
            <xsl:for-each select="$modules/comp">
              <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('../myfile/', .))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </content>
        <count>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($modules)" />
        </count>
    </page>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 2.0 you could write a compact line like `<xsl:copy-of select="document($modules/comp/(concat('../line/', .))"/>` but with XSLT 1.0 the for-each should do.

Comment: Hi Martin, unfortunately not - I think I still need to call the template from this point. Trying above, with file location added, I only get the first document output:   <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('../myfile/', string($modules/comp)))"/> . Although the count does go up. Maybe it's looping but not adding the docs?